# Firebase Promise chain terminate in catch block

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to exit http function if first catch block is reached.
I'm doing following

```
    .then() <- start work related with database
            .then()
            .then()
            .catch(error => { <- Here I want to catch errors with firebase database and exit function.
              console.log(error)
              response.status(500).send(error)
            })
            .then() <- Here I want to send FCM message if there was no database errors
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              response.status(200).send("Success") <- Main work with database was finished. I still want to send http 200 and don't care about FCM errors.
           })
           .then(() => {
              response.status(200).send("Success")
           }) <-This catch block should be fired if there was an issue with FCM
```

Problem is that function continue to run after first catch block. How to stop this chain properly in first catch block? Thanks

Comment: erm. What the actual what ?

Comment: I have 2 catch blocks in Promise chain. And if first catch block was triggered, I don't want to continue. If not triggered, do other stuff...

Comment: Have a look at how to use `Promise.all`, also see Firebase batch functions if using firestore.

Comment: Ron Royston, I know what is Promise.all.
I still want to have 2 catch blocks. One for database stuff and one for FCM stuff. I don't want to merge them into one catch block

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, using a combination a propagated values and a top-level sentinel:

```
let bail = false

doWork()
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    return true  // indicate success
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    return false  // indicate error
})
.then(isPriorSuccessful => {
    if (!isPriorSuccessful) {
        bail = true
        return null
    }
    else {
        // do more stuff here, return a promise
        return doMoreWork()
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
})
.then(() => {
    if (bail) {
        res.status(500).send("NOT OK")
        return
    }
    console.log("Just before the end")
    res.send("OK")
})
```

Comment: Late to the party, and with apologies if I'm misunderstanding something, but would another approach be to set the sentinel in the catch and return Promise.reject(), forcing it to jump to the next catch, wherein the sentinel can be checked to see whether console output is required?